# convert type of collection using linq and c#

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have

```
ICollection<MyPoco> myPocos
```

MyPoco has a name property, I could loop through collection and get each name and put it in a second collection.

```
foreach (var myPoco in myPocos)
{
  myNameCollection.Add(myPoco.Name);
}
```

Is there a more succint way using linq/c#.

Comment: You have to *select* it using LINQ. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
myNameCollection = myPocos.Select(mp => mp.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) to project source into a collection of names:

```
var names = myPocos.Select(p => p.Name);
```

And `AddRange` to your collection:

```
myNameCollection.AddRange(names);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
var myNameCollection = from poco in myPocos select poco.Name;
```

You will get an `IEnumerable<string>` as a result.